# Styling Agora Live Transcoding Layout

Tags: javascript, webrtc, live-streaming, agora.io, transcoding

I am using agora web libraries with Javascript to build an application that has live streaming with a live transcoding feature.

Is there any way to style the tiles shown in the Agora Live Transcoding layout?

Documentation for live  is here: https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web/interfaces/agorartc.transcodinguser.html

All I see is the **alpha, height, uid, width, x, y, zOrder** shown in the documentation. Can we add for example, a border radius, border color to the tile within the Agora live transcoding layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Agora recording composite mode only supports the listed properties in the docs. If you want to set things like border weight etc, you can use the Agora individual recording and composite the videos together yourself using a tool like ffmpeg.